# How to simulate pressing the Android menu button in ARC

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I'm using ARC Welder to test an APK in Chrome (on Windows). It works mostly fine but the app uses an old-style Android menu, opened by either pressing the hardware button on old devices, or touching the "3 vertical dots" soft button on newer ones.
However the ARC window doesn't use a menu button nor does there seem to be a keyboard shortcut to open the menu (not that I could find anyway).
Any ideas?

(Note: I know Google has more or less depricated there old style Android menus. But this is in an old APK).

Comment: The PgUp key is what works on the emulator -- does this work with ARC?

Comment: Implement a keyevent listener that shows the menu.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sadly PgUp doesn't do the trick in ARC.

Comment: @Theyouthis I guess that would work but I was hoping not having to mondify the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARC does not provide a way of simulating an Android menu button. We have thought about providing a button in the window frame, like we do for the back button, but we have not moved forward with it. Feel free to star [the bug for it](http://crbug.com/290361)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (Win key is to prevent Windows opening the Start menu):
https://github.com/vladikoff/chromeos-apk#tested-apps

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd> should work as well but most keyboards lack that key.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290361#c9